# What could be the possible equivalent of chef if tagged to be used in ansible?

Tags: ansible, chef-infra

Looking to find a solution to if-tagged usage of Chef in ansible. The tags are created in the chef server using knife command, and it can be called in recipe if-tagged.

What is the equivalent way to do this in ansible?

So, in the code below, if the node is tagged prod, it is picking up the prod template from the cookbook and copying to the node's destination path.

```
if tagged?('prod')
  template '/etc/prod.yml' do
  source 'prod.erb'
  action :create
end
else
template '/etc/qa.yml' do
  source 'qa.erb'
  action :create
  end
end
```

Comment: IT may be more useful to be more specific in your use case here. However you might want to read up here,https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

Comment: hi, i have updated the comment above with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making use of groups feature in Ansible.
For example, define your inventory file as below

```
[all_hosts:children]
prod
qa

[prod]
prod_hostname

[qa]
qa_hostname
```

In your playbook, you can write conditionals as below for the respective tasks:

`when: inventory_hostname in groups.prod` for executing the prod specific task

`when: inventory_hostname in groups.qa` for executing the prod specific task

Do, ensure the way you should be accessing the **inventory_hostname** as the syntax varies, you may have to use `{{inventory_hostname}}` in some versions of ansbile.

Comment: Thanks, i was able to use and test this logic successfully.

Comment: Great! glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure "how" you define/tag your hosts whether they are production hosts or not. But here's an example using host naming conventions.

```
  - set_fact: myenv="prod"
    when: ( ansible_hostname | search("-p$")) or ( ansible_hostname | search("-prod$") )
```

This analyzes the hostname of the target server and if the hostname ends with -p or -prod, a variable (fact) called `myenv` with value `prod` is created. You can of course also use other ansible variables or check on the target for existing files or config settings, etc.

You can then use the `copy` module:

```
  - name: Copy PROD config on PROD hosts
    copy: src=/srv/ansible/configs/prod.yml dest=/etc/prod.yml owner=root group=root mode=0644
    when: myenv == "prod"

  - name: Copy QA config on non-PROD hosts
    copy: src=/srv/ansible/configs/qa.yml dest=/etc/qa.yml owner=root group=root mode=0644
    when: myenv is undefined
```

Note I added `when: myenv is undefined` because the `set_fact` above only defines the `myenv` variable when the hostname lookup matched the prod naming convention. For all other hosts this does not apply and for ansible the variable is not set in this case. You could create a second `set_fact` where you define your `qa` hosts, too. In this case you can adjust the `when` condition of the "Copy QA.." task to something like `when: myenv is undefined or myenv != "prod"`.

Or use a fixed fact variable (without different environments in this case), simpler but less dynamic:

```
  - set_fact: myprod=yes
    when: ( ansible_hostname | search("-p$")) or ( ansible_hostname | search("-prod$") )

  - name: Copy PROD config on PROD hosts
    copy: src=/srv/ansible/configs/prod.yml dest=/etc/prod.yml owner=root group=root mode=0644
    when: myprod is defined

  - name: Copy QA config on all other hosts
    copy: src=/srv/ansible/configs/qa.yml dest=/etc/qa.yml owner=root group=root mode=0644
    when: myprod is undefined
```